# How to convert a tree to a dendrogram in R?

Tags: r, tree, dendrogram

How can I convert a tree (which is the output of my Java program) to a dendrogram in R?

Currently, I am converting the tree into the Newick format, using the suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612579/converting-a-tree-to-newick-format-java). And then I use the `ape` package in R to read the Newick-formatted tree:

```
library("ape")
cPhylo <- read.tree(file = "gc.tree")
```

Finally I use `as.hclust` in R to convert the tree into a dendrogram:

```
dendrogram <- as.hclust(gcPhylo)
```

However, the dendrogram requires the branch lengths. Although I insert the branch lengths, I am getting an error saying that the tree is not ultrametric:

> Error in as.hclust.phylo(gcPhylo) : the tree is not ultrametric

I guess I am doing something wrong while inserting the branch lengths.

Is there any other way that I can follow? Or how can I insert the branch lengths while converting the tree into the Newick format? Equal branch lengths would be fine.

Comment: See the help for `?as.hclust` - this can only convert an object from class `twins` to `hclust`.  Thus your code will definitely not work.  As to how to make it work, I'm sorry but I haven't a clue.

Comment: Then, it means there is nothing to do with the branch lengths. So it is not possible to convert it using as.hclust.. Then I need to find another way.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but it has inadequate answers so far.  Since I had the same problem, and my googlefoo was having problems finding the answer, here you go:

```
library("ape")
cPhylo <- read.tree(file = "gc.tree")
dendrogram <- chronos(cPhylo)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but all of the previous answers require the tree to be made ultrametric before being converted to a dendrogram object.

You can use the [DECIPHER](http://DECIPHER.codes) package to read a dendrogram object from a Newick formatted file:

```
dend <- ReadDendrogram(path_to_newick_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in fact that your "gc.tree" isn't ultrametric. Make sure that the distance from the root to each tip is the same. The following code works:

```
library('ape')
tree <- read.tree(text='(((A:4.2,B:4.2):3.1,C:7.3):6.3,D:13.6);')
is.ultrametric(tree)
is.binary.tree(tree)
is.rooted(tree)
hc <- as.hclust.phylo(tree)
```

but make the tree non-ultrametric (note D's branch length):

```
tree <- read.tree(text='(((A:4.2,B:4.2):3.1,C:7.3):6.3,D:15);')
```

and as.hclust.phylo will raise an error.